# need to create file in with a command which will list files in the directory

Tags: linux

need a help

Put in a file mastertheLS the command line that will:

list the files and directories of the current directory.
Ignore the hidden files, the "." and the "..".
Separate the results with commas only.
Order them by ascending order of access time (the newest first).
Have the directories ends with a /.

tried to ask chat gpt but the code was wrong
ind . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name ".*" -exec sh -c 'if [ -d "$1" ]; then echo "$1/"; else echo "$1"; fi' sh {} ; | sort

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `ls` command provides you with the list, then just transform (`tr`) it to the proper format.

```bash
$ ls -tp | tr "\n" ","
```

Sample output:

```
vite.config.ts,node_modules/,package-lock.json,tsconfig.app.json,tsconfig.json,tsconfig.node.json,README.md,env.d.ts,index.html,package.json,public/,src/,
```

### Explanation:

Get the list ordered by time (`-t`) and directories [appended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265127/how-do-get-ls-to-list-directories-with-a-trailing-forward-slash) with `/` (`-p`):

```bash
$ ls -tp
```

Note 1: you can apply `-r` switch to reverse the time ordering (`ls -rtp`).

Note 2: to include hidden files use `-a` switch (`ls -atp`)

Then just transform the list replacing newlines (\n) with commas

```bash
$ tr "\n" ","
```

Finally, save the result in a file using std [redirections](https://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_05_01.html):

```bash
$ ls -tp | tr "\n" "," > mastertheLS
```